# weak exogeneity in VAR analysis

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, granger-causality, exogeneity

I have a problem interpreting the notion of "weak exogeneity in a VAR process". Assuming we have the following structural form:

$y_t = b_{12}z_t + \gamma_{11}y_{t-1} + \gamma_{12}z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{yt}$

$z_t = b_{21}y_t + \gamma_{21}y_{t-1} + \gamma_{22}z_{t-1} + \epsilon_{zt}$

Does weak exogeneity imply that either $b_{12}=0$ or $b_{21}=0$, but not both?

Comment: From what I found myself now, setting one of the coefficients above to zero will result in weak exogeneity, implying that respective variable does not Granger Cause the other. Weak exogeneity is permissible for a VAR model. Strict exogeneity would rule the VAR inappropriate in the first place.